# Is there a pure sql() operator for dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to use `dplyr` mixed with pure `sql`. The rationale is that I generally prefer `sql` to the `dsl` supplied by `dplyr`; however the `mutate()` verb is useful.  So a workflow might look like

```
result =  my.df >%> sql("select max(a) a_max,b,c [from X ?] 
                  where b in ('b1','b2) group by b,c
                  having count(1) > 1 
                  order by a desc, b") 
               >%> mutate(c = c * 100) 
               >%> sql("select a_max,b,c from X order by 1 desc, 3 desc")
```

Note: this is not a debate on merits of using `dsl` vs `sql`: that can be a lengthy and nuanced one and there are solid rationales for either.  I am suspecting that to get what is requested will require digging for `github` repos specifically designed for this but wanted to check if I had missed some capability within `dplyr` or the wider `tidy-verse`.

Another note:  There is a highly proficient user of `dplyr` that I work with. I do not wish to interrupt/change his flow. I would like to be able to insert sql's in the middle of `dplyr` workflow chains since I am comfortable writing complex multi level nested queries - and do so much faster than the `dplyr` dsl.

Comment: It could be perhaps useful https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/sql-translation.html

Comment: As @tmfmnk mentions, I think sql() from dbplyr is what you're looking for. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dbplyr/vignettes/sql.html

Comment: @tmfmnk  `dbplyr` is a useful package to investigate. Please make this an answer

Comment: @IceCreamToucan  I'm aware of `sqldf` : but afaik (and as you also implied) it does not support chaining

Comment: Are you trying to operate on R data.frames or tables on a database?

Comment: `R` `data.frame` s

Comment: @javadba, `sqldf` can use dot to refer to the input in a dplyr chain.  See my comments under the `sqldf` answer.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck  Your comment(s) do not appear there?

Comment: Scroll down until you see the comments under @IceCramToucan's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try looking at the `tidyquery` package. Link:https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyquery/index.html by Ian Cook

Example:

```
planes %>%
  filter(engine == "Turbo-fan") %>%
  query("SELECT manufacturer AS maker, COUNT(*) AS num_planes GROUP BY maker") %>%
  arrange(desc(num_planes)) %>%
  head(5)

#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   maker            num_planes
#>   <chr>                 <int>
#> 1 BOEING                 1276
#> 2 BOMBARDIER INC          368
#> 3 AIRBUS                  331
#> 4 EMBRAER                 298
#> 5 AIRBUS INDUSTRIE        270
```

Comment: Thanks this is part of `tidyverse` which is exactly what was asked for.

Answer (score 3):

```
library(dplyr)
library(sqldf)

dplyr_sqldf <- function(df, query){
  sqldf(query) %>% 
    group_by_at(group_vars(df))
}

ex <- data.frame(a = rep(1:2, each = 10), b = 1:20)

ex %>% 
  group_by(a) %>% 
  dplyr_sqldf('
  select  a
          , b*2 as b
  from    df
  ') %>% 
  summarise(avg = mean(b))

# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#       a   avg
#   <int> <dbl>
# 1     1    11
# 2     2    31
```

Actually, as mentioned in the comments, you can do this without an extra function

```
ex %>% 
  group_by(a) %>% 
  do(sqldf('select a, b*2 as b from [.]')) %>% 
  summarise(avg = mean(b))
```

Comment: We can get rid of the helper function by using dot to refer to the input: `ex %>% 
  group_by(a) %>% 
  do(sqldf('select a, b*2 as b from [.]')) %>% 
  summarise(avg = mean(b))`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck Thanks, was trying to figure that out. Do you know why that retains the groups, but this doesn't? `ex %>% 
  group_by(a) %>% 
  {sqldf('select a, b*2 as b from [.]')} %>% 
  summarise(avg = mean(b))`

Comment: @IceCreamToucan, In dplyr dot refers to the entire data frame even within a `group_by` unless within a `do`.

Comment: Also note that we don't really even need dplyr at all. This works: `sqldf("select a, avg(b*2) avg from ex group by a")`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck  My use case is to embed the `sql` within existing `dplyr` flows that include `mutate`.

Comment: Here a reproducible example of using `sqldf` within a `mutate` where `BOD` is built into R. `BOD %>% mutate(frac = sqldf("select demand / sum(demand) frac from [.]")$frac)`   You don't really need both dplyr and sqldf for this simple example but  it illustrates using both together.